# Do you think we would need a CDN in front of an api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, cdn, gateway, web-application-firewall

We are using AWS and using the Kong API gateway hosted in AWS.

Do you think we would need a CDN in front this API gateway?

We don't need much caching, as well as we can attach the WAF in AWS to the alb.

Comment: I slightly reworded your question for readability, but well: I feel it is too broad, and doesn't fit the scope of this community. You should turn to the help center to learn how/what to ask, and improve this question to be in the scope of this community.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a common pattern for API Protection in AWS.

Here is a good article by AWS in setting up CloudFront and WAF with AWS API Gateway, though the same principals apply to any API Gateway:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-i/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I read the blog, nothing specific on api gateway security/caching with CloudFront. WAF is the real protection which can be integrated with an ALB as I had mentioned earlier